# Earnest as a noun

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, grammar

So the title of the question, I believe, speaks for itself.

I am racking my brain, thesaurus and dictionary to think of a suitable word which would accurately describe one being earnest in relation to using it as a 'tool of the trade'.

The closest I could come up with but which doesn't feel accurate enough for me is `sincerity`

Can anyone else think of a word which would properly demonstrate "earnesism" ?

Appreciated

Comment: How about "dedication"?

Comment: @SvenYargs I had thought of dedication, but for me one being earnest shows a slightly more reserved self confidence in their abilities and prove results. One can be dedicated but bad at what they do ..

Comment: So you want something that means "earnest and competent"?

Comment: _Earnestness_ is the noun form of _earnest_. Why can't you just go with that?

Comment: @SvenYargs I guess when you break it down into its primaries, sure.. Am I wrong in believing earnest carries more weight with its meaning in that you actually produce results ? My (limited) thoughts were that earnest was 'dedicated + competent' `resulting from or showing sincere and intense conviction.` resulting being my key reasoning.

Comment: @Nicole well.. Consider me embarrassed. I guess my research abilities as as dismal as my grammatical. Thank you! Guess it just doesnt feel like a 'tool'

Comment: Per Merriam-Webster _earnest_ as an adjective can mean "characterized by or proceeding from an intense and serious state of mind" or "grave, important." In neither case is the ability to accomplish something meaningful implicit in the definition.

Comment: Pogrindis, I don't understand your "tool of the trade" requirement. Can you clarify that?

Comment: _Earnest_ is a noun, too, though it mostly just collocates with the preposition _in_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *‘Receive it, lord!’ he said: ‘in **earnest** of other things that shall be given back. But if I may counsel you in the use of your own, do not use it — yet! Be wary!’*

Answer (score -1):

What about 
intentional sincerity?

Comment: or earnest intention?

Comment: but actually, I apologize as I have not provided a noun :-(

Comment: I get the reasoning behind your answer, I guess I was looking for something that wasn't there, best answer I got was in the comments by way of @Nicole `Earnestness`

Comment: Very sensible, she definitely provided cleanest answer!